# Create a histogram or frequency list of most popular commands used in bash session

Tags: bash

Is there an active way to collect the most frequently used commands used in a bash session?

If not, by what means can I start to write a script or run a background process to achieve this?

For example I would have a report I could generate in a session that would look like

```
cd  25%
ls  40%
cat 35%
```

Comment: `history` is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one would show output near intended format:

```
history | awk '($2 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/) { ++a[$2]; t = length($2); if (t > l) l = t; } END { for (i in a) printf("%s%" (l - length(i) + 1) "s%5.2f%%\n", i, " ", (a[i] * 100 / NR)); }'
```

Example output:

```
...
cd           6.00%
ls          12.00%
cat          1.60%
...
```

You could also sort it with `... | sort -n -k2` or `... | sort -n -k2 -r`.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was trying to obtain, any place in particular that is good to read up on AWK should I want to decipher this a bit more?

Comment: The GNU Awk manual could be a good one: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html :)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the output of the `history` command, and count occurrences of the command field.

```
history | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Will print a list of executed commands and the amount of times they were executed. Then, you can fetch the total amount of commands executed with `history | wc -l`, and then perform the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following

```
history | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

If you frequently use pipes like the one above, you will probably need to write a bash parser to get also the other commands than just `history`.

Comment: `history | cut -f4- -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`
I had to tweak cut to get this approach working for me.